# Is it possible to track bodies with kinect when it is vertical instead of horizontal?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm wondering if there is a way to rotate the image that i get from the kinect with 90 degrees, so that i can hang the kinect verticaly, and like this still track bodies ?

Because when you hang it vertical now it doesn't track anything, which i guess is normal since it's only programmed to look for bodies when it is vertical, but is there a way around this ?

I tried to find a way to rotate the WriteableBitmap, like i found some examples online, but without any luck. I think if I should do anything i should do it in this part of the code:

private void Reader_ColorFrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        // ColorFrame is IDisposable
        using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (colorFrame != null)
            {
                FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;

                using (KinectBuffer colorBuffer = colorFrame.LockRawImageBuffer())
                {
                    this.colorBitmap.Lock();

                    // verify data and write the new color frame data to the display bitmap
                    if ((colorFrameDescription.Width == this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth) && (colorFrameDescription.Height == this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight))
                    {

                        colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToIntPtr(
                            this.colorBitmap.BackBuffer,
                            (uint)(colorFrameDescription.Width * colorFrameDescription.Height * 4),
                            ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

                        this.colorBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight));
                    }


                    this.colorBitmap.Unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i'm not able to figure out what to do to make the rotation happen.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you fix this yet ? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Working on the color image won't help you, since the Body Tracking algorithm is based on the depth data only.

Also, if you need to use the Microsoft Kinect SDK there is no way to "change" the algorithm and the data passed to it. Indeed you would need to rotate the depth image before it is passed to the body tracker, which is simply not possible with this SDK.

I am not sure if this can be done using other frameworks. What you can do, however, is to put some lens in front of the ones used by the device, to rotate the image. Or you can dissasemble the device and try to rotate the lenses by 90 degrees... It's up to you.

Hope this helps.